# Re-render Blazor Component

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-blazor

I have a catalogue page that renders a Blazor component which displays a list of products with the following code:

```cs
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<ProductList>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new { MinimumPrice = Model.MinimumPrice, MaximumPrice = Model.MaximumPrice }))
```

Now, I want to change the values of `MinimumPrice` and `MaximumPrice` from the catalogue page and have the blazor component re-rendered after the values have changed.

How can I do that from the catalogue page?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any problems with my post? If you have question, feel free to ask. And if it can help, you can [set it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the razor view and then update the blazor component?

You can submit a form to change the Model.MinimumPrice, because you can't change the Model

in view, it's from **server side**, so you should change it in server side too.

This is the demo:

blazor component:

```
<p>Min:@MinimumPrice</p>

@code {
[Parameter]
public int MinimumPrice { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public int MaximumPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Razor view:

```
<form method="post">
Change min to<input type="text" name="value"/>
<input type="submit" value="ok" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
<component type="typeof(S42111.Components.ProductList)" render-mode="Static" param-MinimumPrice="Model.MinimumPrice" param-MaximumPrice="10" />
```

server side:

```
[BindProperty]
    public int MinimumPrice { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        MinimumPrice = 1;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int value)
    {
        this.MinimumPrice = value;
        return Page();
    }
```

Result:
[image]